# How does the AWS java SDK determine it's default region

Tags: amazon-web-services

Can someone explain how the AWS Java SDK determines it's default endpoint?

```
AmazonEC2Client client = new AmazonEC2Client(...);

// If this method is not called, how does it know where to connect?
client.setEndpoint("ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS SDK for Java defaults to **us-east-1** for all clients.

There's a lot of great information on the default and how to select a different region in the AWS SDK for Java Developer Guide:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/java-dg-region-selection.html

Answer (score 2):

It doesnt determine any thing as such, all the API's SDK's default end point will be us-east itself.

Answer (score 2):

```
AmazonEC2 ec2 = AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.defaultClient();
DescribeAvailabilityZonesResult zones = ec2.describeAvailabilityZones();
AvailabilityZone zone = zones.getAvailabilityZones().get(0);
String currentRegion = zone.getRegionName();
```

Comment: Nice simple way to find out what region is actually being used by the API, instead of trying to hack in to or reproduce the client-side provider-chain logic.